# echo the set of variables while going through a loop

Tags: bash, shell, loops, variables, sh

Can someone help me. I've been trying alternatives but I still get the same output.

Here is my script

```
  #!/bin/sh

  field1="a"
  field2="s"
  field3="d"
  field4="f"
  field5="g"

  for i in {1..5}
  do

    var1="field"$i
    echo $var1

    var2="$"$var1
    echo $var2 

    echo $field1

  done
```

Here is my output

```
  field1
  $field1
  a
  field2
  $field2
  a
  field3
  $field3
  a
  field4
  $field4
  a
  field5
  $field5
  a
```

what I'm trying to do is get an output like

```
a
s
d
f
g
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [`${!var1}`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) — a Bash-specific shell parameter expansion.

```
field1="a"
field2="s"
field3="d"
field4="f"
field5="g"

for i in {1..5}
do
    var1="field"$i
    echo $var1=${!var1}
done
```

Output:

```
field1=a
field2=s
field3=d
field4=f
field5=g
```

I got that with both `bash` and `sh` running the script.  Clearly, if you don't include `$var1=` in the `echo`, you get just the single letters you ask for.

You should also consider whether your fields should be stored in a Bash [array](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arrays).

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use arrays? maybe something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

  field[1]="a"
  field[2]="s"
  field[3]="d"
  field[4]="f"
  field[5]="g"

  for i in {1..5}
  do

    echo ${field[i]}

  done
```

Comment: I have a php script that assigns value to my bash variables and creating a variable for each value passed looks easier :)

Answer (score 1):

When you are not sure how many field variables you have, you can use something like:

```
set | grep "^field" | cut -d= -f2
```

`set` lists all the variables; `grep` selects the ones starting with 'field'; `cut` removes the value of the variable, leaving just the name.

Comment: If you only want `field` followed by a number, then `grep -E '^field[0-9]+='`.  If you've got a PCRE-enabled `grep` (modern GNU `grep`, for example), you can even use trailing context (positive lookahead) and `-o` to get what you want direct from `set | grep -o -P '^field\d+(?==)'`.