# Unset is not useful? (Korn shell)

Tags: shell, variables, unix

I'm reading this:

> You can delete a variable with the command `unset` *varname*. Normally this is not useful, since all variables that don't exist are assumed to be null, i.e., equal to empty string "". But if you use the option `nounset` which causes the shell to indicate an error when it encounters an undefined variable, then you may be interested in `unset`.

My first question is: I cannot see why the use of `unset` be not useful; if I want to put my variable to `null` I can use it (or set *variable=""* or *variable=*). On the other hand, if I have a variable that doesn't exist, I don't know why I should have to use it..

My second question is: Why may I be interested in `unset` in that case?

Comment: Where does the quote come from?

Comment: @Ed Heal: http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix/ksh/ , chapter 3.4 [1993, :-) ]

Answer (score 1):

There is a relevant difference between unset and empty variables.
When you can't tell in front which variables will be used, you can process the output of `set` (examples: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43419722/3220113 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/28104421/3220113 ).
You might have a situaton where you have sourced a read-only config file, but you do not want all lines set in your environment. In that case you might want to `unset` the settings you do not need.
When you write some utility that uses some variables, you do not want to leave garbage in the environment. Next to using `local` variables using `unset` is another possibility.

Comment: I think I'm beginning to understand. The first thing I ask you is about your first assertion: the {"", 0, null, $var - declared variable without value, etc} is another thing with respect to what results from unset; so I ask you what exactely unset does. I read it is equivalent to var= or to the "" as you have seen in the quoted text. A bit confused.. I need some further help.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the answer to my question.

1) If you need to remove the *definition* and the *content* of a variable you can use `unset` command. However, unless you turn on the `nounset` set option,  Korn Shell will allow using variables which don't exist, and it will default the content of such a variable as an empty string. That's why  you normally don't use `unset`: because you normally leave the `nounset` option off and test variables via conditional logic. Hence in these cases, i.e. the inhibition of the use of a variable, it is not useful. (Obviously, it remains useful for deleting variables - as noted by @Walter A, i.e. "" is not `unset`, the complete removal of the variable.)

2) That said, it follows that if you use the `nounset`, `unset` command makes sense. Indeed, if you unset a variable, the shell will disallow using it.